# Is there a way to count the value of a cell under the criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've been toying with this problem for some time but no matter how hard I try, I can't wrap my head around the syntax of a command.

Screenshot of Spreadsheet:
[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

First thing's first. The layout of this spreadsheet can't be changed in any way, making this problem a whole lot more difficult to solve. I've added a screenshot above of what the spreadsheet looks like at the moment. It is currently just a test-sheet as the master-sheet is having real data inputted into it.

So the first problem is searching the array "D:H" for the shot listed in the "I" column. For example, I want to count how many times "Vodka" appears in the array (D:H).

The second problem is I then want to sum each number contained in the cell below the criteria. Following the same example, given the criteria "Vodka" (I4), I want to be able to sum all of the cells under any cell containing the word "Vodka".

The third problem is then to multiply it by the "Amount Sold". Once again, following the same example, I would multiply it by the cells "C5" and "C9" as both of the cocktails have a shot of vodka in them.

The last problem really wraps it all up in a tight little bow. All of this will need to be adaptable to adding, removing and changing cocktails to this list, as well as the shots that are in them and the shots that are being searched.

Again, this is all test information as I don't feel as though I should be putting out anything involving my workplace.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Count amount of vodka in D:H

```
=COUNTIF(D4:H13, "Vodka")
```

Sum of all Vodka

```
=SUMIF(D5:H5,"Vodka", D4:H4)
```

Instead of Hard-coding "Vodka" in the cell you should use reference to the cells. This makes expanding the table easier

If you have the value the last multiplication is no problem.